# What is the proper way implement a global $wp_rewrite?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, rewrite-rules, actions

The below code works correctly, but I don't know if it is proper coding. Can anyone confirm or comment on the code?

```
add_action('init', 'news_rewrite');
function news_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_permastruct('news', 'news/%year%/%postname%/', true, 1);
    add_rewrite_rule('news/([0-9]{4})/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?news=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^news/([0-9]{4})/?','index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to define $wp_rewrite in your function.  The add_permastruct() and add_rewrite_rule() functions take care of that for you.  Try removing the "global $wp_rewrite;" line and see if your code still works.

The add_permastruct() function [currently accepts three parameters](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/rewrite.php#L54).  There is some backwards-compatibility logic in the function to correct for calls using the old four-parameter structure, but you might want to change that line to use the current three parameter structure, like this:

```
add_permastruct( 'news', 'news/%year%/%postname%/', array('with_front' => true, 'ep_mask' => 1) );
```